# join data frames in two separate lists R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, inner-join

I have a 2 lists of 6 data frames each.

```
listofdf_1 <- list(a, b, c, d, e, f)
listofdf_2 <- list(a2, b2, c2, d2, e2, f2)
```

I want to `inner_join` data frame a with a2, b with b2, c with c2 etc.
The join column is : ID1

I've written a function :

```
merge_on_id <- function(x, y, join_field) {
  require(dplyr)
  inner_join(x, y, by = join_field)
}
```

Now I'm joining one by one: `merge_on_id(listofdf_1[[1]], listofdf_2[[1]], by = "ID1")` etc.

I'm wondering if there is a way to join all six in a single line instead of having to repeat for each element of the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need to `inner_join` corresponding elements of `lists`, we can use `Map`.

```
 Map(inner_join, listofdf_1, listofdf_2, MoreArgs=list(by='ID1'))
```

#### data

```
listofdf_1 <- list(a= data.frame(ID1= LETTERS[1:3], Value= 1:3, stringsAsFactors=FALSE),
          b = data.frame(ID1= LETTERS[4:7], V1= 4:7, stringsAsFactors=FALSE))

listofdf_2 <- list(a2= data.frame(ID1= LETTERS[1:5], Value= 6:10, stringsAsFactors=FALSE), 
      b2 = data.frame(ID1= LETTERS[4:9], V1= 4:9, stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
```

Comment: thanks! the inner join in MAP, is it from dplyr or is it base?

Comment: @vagabond It's a base R option, but we could do this with `dplyr`, possibly in a couple of steps (I thought you wanted a single step answer).

Comment: @vagabond It depends upon the number of steps.  Also, you can check the speed using `system.time` or `microbenchmark`.